# What is the daily logged-in users count?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

How many logged-in users are there every day? I'm looking for the StackOverflow numbers in particular.

Can we get these numbers anywhere at all? Is there any historical data (monthly or even on an ad-hoc basis)?

Comment: Do you mean logged in, or active?

Comment: @simchona: good point; I interpreted 'loggedusers' as 'logged-in' when I cleaned up the question; could mean active too..

Comment: @simchona good point, I would like to see any number of logged in users expecially with devision into geographical regions - NA vs Europe